# Service Cloud for Slack - Create Swarm - No channel options presented

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

I just installed the Service Cloud for Slack app (into Slack) and then configured my Lightning Service Console to begin swarms in the feed layout

- I followed the (lengthy) documentation in [Setup Service Cloud for Slack](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.set_up_slack.htm&type=5)
- My Slack Workspace `Service Cloud for Slack` app is properly mapped to my org
- Running user has necessary credentials per doc above.

Yet, when I begin a Swarm on a Case in the Service Console, the associated OOTB Flow `Begin Swarming`

- prompts to add members
- creates the swarm but
- DOES NOT PROMPT for the Slack channel

so, nothing appears in the Slack Workspace

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many configuration steps, scattered in several places.

The key concept is that `Setup | Swarming` is more about Case swarming with the option to plug-in a collaboration tool.  That is, one could Swarm entirely within SFDC (the default) and not involve an outside collaboration tool (e.g. Slack)

But, if you were like me, you thought you were setting up a tight integration between SFDC and Slack and by doing the numerous setup steps, you'd have something working.

So, what did I forget?

In `Setup > Swarming`, way at the bottom as *Optional Step 7*, you need to set the Collaboration tool to `Slack` as shown

[image]

Admittedly, this is covered in the doc under [Setup Swarming, Step 6](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.set_up_swarming.htm&type=5) but since Step 5 (Expert Finder) didn't apply to us, I stopped reading and the Optional portion in the `Setup > Swarming` lulled me into complacency